# How to read files/folders inside the assets folder using Ionic Capacitor Filesystem plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, ionic5

Previously, with the [ionic File plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file), reading a folder and it's content, specifically a folder inside the assets folder was done like this.

`this.file.listDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'www/assets/data').then(response => {}`

The new capacitor file system has a [readdir](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem/#method-readdir-0) method which expects you to pass a [FileSystemDirectory](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/apis/filesystem/#type-432).
Which of those options do I have to pass to allow me to read the `www/assets/data` folder? Essentially, what's the equivalent of `this.file.applicationDirectory`?

Comment: If this is solved could you please say which FileSystemDirectory did you end up using for the capacitor filesystem plugin? currently facing the same issue. Im trying to point to a file in assets/audio/... in my project but cant figure out how to do it for iOS. I have it working already for the web.

Comment: @ilpianoforte did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/68474452/3933590?

Comment: I did. But I dont see the answer to my question. At the end of your question you have asked "Essentially, what's the equivalent of this.file.applicationDirectory?" and I was asking you since in the answer that you have provided you seem to have used `this.file.applicationDirectory`, so based on that i cant find out which of the values of the Directory Enum you have used.

Comment: Did an answer ever come of this?  This new filesystem is terribly thought out. I can't access anything.  Can't find application folder either and it forces me to use an enum folder

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to read Capacitor public folder with Filesystem plugin

Comment: It actually is. I have added an answer to the question.

Comment: Well, I mean with capacitor plugin. On your answer looks like you are using cordova file plugin

Answer (score 0):

I found that the data that `www/assets` is now `public/assets`.
The code

```
this.file.listDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'www/assets/data').then(response => {})
```

becomes (this works with the new capacitor filesystem plugin).

```
this.file.listDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'public/assets/data').then(response => {})
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many approach to access files inside assets folder and i found below solution as working one.

- First you have to access your file under assets folder using fetch
- Convert your buffer to Base64
- And then Base64 can be written on your directory using Filesystem plugin.

below is code for downloading file from assets folder.

```
downloadFileFromAssets(fileName:string){
    fetch("/assets/"+fileName)
    .then(async response=> await response.arrayBuffer())
    .then(async (response) => {
      var base64 = btoa(
        new Uint8Array(response)
          .reduce((data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte), '')
      );
      Filesystem.writeFile({
        data: base64,
        directory:Directory.Documents,
        path:fileName,
      }).then(r=>{
        console.log("File URI : ", r.uri);
      });
    });
}
```

might be this one would help someone.